# Prove If p is an odd prime, and $p^k$ divides $v$, then $p^k$ also has to divide $u$.

Tags: number-theory

hey guys can you help me with this one:

Assume,

$$u^2 = \frac{4n v^2}{v^2 - 4}$$

If $p$ is an odd prime, and $p^k$ divides $v$, prove that $p^k$ also has to divide $u$.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Is it possible for $p^{2k}$ to divide the denominator of $u^2$?

Comment: Notice that $v^2 -4 = (v-2)(v+2)$. Can $p$ divide either of these factors?

Comment: Right, my comment should read "is it possible for $p$ to divide the denominator of $u^2$," not $p^{2k}$.

Comment: Unusually fun problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if $p$ is a prime, $ p^n$ divides $x$ and $p$ does not  divide $y$ then $p^n$ divides $\frac{x}{y}$.

In our case we have $x=4nv^2$, $y=v^2-4$ and $n=2k$, notice that $u^2=\frac{x}{y}$.

It follows that $p^{2k}$ divides $u^2$ and so $p^k$ divides $u$.